# Counting the occurrences of frequent pairs efficiently

Tags: python, pyspark, data-mining, apriori

I have a large database of baskets (N = 31101), and I want to count the number of occurrences of frequent pairs. I am using the `get_sup` function to do this. I am able to get the count of frequent items with minutes. However, getting the count for frequent pairs is taking too long as there are 269745 pairs and all these pairs have to be checked in N baskets.

I am doing it using for loop within the `get_sup` function. Are there any other tricks in Spark that I can use to do it more efficiently.

```
def get_sup(x):
  x_sup = 0
  for t in shared_itemset.value:
    if x.issubset(t):
    #if set({x}).issubset(set(t)):
      x_sup +=1
  if x_sup >= sup:
      return x, x_sup
  else:
      return ()

data = sc.textFile('browsing.txt')

itemset = data.map(lambda line: ([item for item in line.strip().split(' ')]))
shared_itemset = sc.broadcast(itemset.map(lambda x: frozenset(x)).collect())

c1 = data.flatMap(lambda line: line.strip().split(' ')).distinct()
c1 = c1.map(lambda x : frozenset({x}))
print(c1.count())----------------------------------------------- 12592

f1 = c1.map(get_sup).filter(lambda x: x)
print(f1.count())----------------------------------------------- 735

f1.persist()
f1m = f1.map(lambda x: tuple(x[0]))
f1c = f1m.cartesian(f1m).map(lambda x: frozenset(x[0]+x[1])).filter(lambda x: len(x)>1).distinct()

# f1c has 269745 elements and has data structure frozenset({'FRO11987', 'GRO73461'})
 
f2 = f1c.map(get_sup).filter(lambda x: x) pairs
```

Thank you. For the whole dataset use [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w0170SBNaAhxqqOz7SMxvS_dRIhkaJP1/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

This solution may work: for every basket it calculates the possible pairs of its elements, and then checks if `pair` is in those elements. Then it outputs the percentage of baskets that contain said pair.

```py
from itertools import permutations
b1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b2 = [4, 5, 6]
baskets = [b1, b2]
pair = [1, 2]

def finder(baskets, pair):
    baskets_asstr = [''.join(map(str, i)) for i in baskets]
    pairsOfEveryBasket = [["".join(i) for i in permutations(baskets_asstr[j], 2)] for j in range(len(baskets_asstr))]
    zipped = list(zip(baskets_asstr, pairsOfEveryBasket))
    pair_str = "".join([str(i) for i in pair])
    num = 0
    for i in zipped:
        if pair_str in i[1]:
            num += 1
    return (num/len(baskets_asstr)

finder(baskets, pair)
```

Comment: I think my question was not clear. So, I have N baskets and each basket has arbitrary number of items. Now, I have a pair of items (let's say P = (a,b)). I want to get count K from N baskets which have this pair into them. Thank you.

Comment: does order make a difference? say, is P(a,b) equal to P(b,a)?

Comment: @user3443033 I have edited my response maybe it will work